# Input/Output from external file in C++ without adding extra code into main file

Tags: c++, windows, file, input, output

How can I take input from file (`input.txt`) and provide the output into another file (`output.txt`) during compilation / execution of program without adding extra code to the main file. I don't want to use

```
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
```

or

```
file.open("input.txt")
```

etc.

I want that my program will behave like below.
What should I add during compilation / execution of program to achieve this?

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string S;
    cin >> S;
    cout << S;
    return 0;
}
```

**input.txt**

```
Hello, World!
```

**output.txt**

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Do some research about *shell or console **redirection***.

Comment: during compilation you cannot do it without changing the code.

Comment: `a.exe < input.txt > output.txt` ?

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? The question is a bit unclear because you ask for compilation but to take input and produce output you need to run the executable

Comment: @Jarod42 At line:1 char:9
+ .\a.exe < input.txt > output.txt
+         ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

Comment: _@JeevanJoshi_ @Jarod meant you should call your executable like this from the terminal (cmd.exe), not to add that into your code :-P

Comment: You seem to be using an older version of PowerShell where the redirection operators wasn't implemented yet. IIRC you need at least PowerShell 2.0 to be able to use redirection. See e.g. [this PowerShell redirection reference for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: As an alternative, use the old Windows command prompt program `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to a program's [standard input, standard output and standard error streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/std_streams) has nothing to do with the build settings of your program. It only depends on the how the program is started by the parent process.

When starting a child process with [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), in the `lpStartupInfo` parameter, you can specify where the child's standard input, standard output and standard error stream will be piped from/to. For example, you can specify a pipe to and from the parent process. The parent process can then do anything it wants with these pipes. For example, it could feed the contents of the file `input.txt` into the child's standard input, and write the contents of the child's standard output to the file `output.txt`. Or the parent process could simply specify file handles to the files `input.txt` and `output.txt` as the handles for standard input and standard output when creating the child process. That way, the parent process won't have to do any input and output processing itself, as everything will be handled by the operating system.

See the following page from the official Microsoft documentation for further information:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

However, this does not necessarily mean that you will have to write your own program to act as a parent process. The Windows Command Line Shell (`cmd.exe`) can do this for you. You can execute your program and specify that standard input and standard output should be redirected, by calling your program in the following way:

`myprogramname.exe <input.txt >output.txt`

That way, the Windows Command Line Shell (`cmd.exe`) will call `CreateProcess` for you and attach the appropriate file handles to standard input and standard output.